# jQuery Mobile - Some devices (users) not able to read html files which i used inside android app

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, html, css

**When some users open my android application, appear such thing in some devices, not in all, but maybe 5% of devices. Till now i dont know whats problem** Maybe i should add `setAllowUniversalAccessFromFileURLs`. but i dont know how to check it, because in my phone application is working.

***The problem is below:***

[image]

**My code in android application**

```
    MainActivity

    WebView webView;
    String current_page_url = "file:///android_asset/web/index.html";

    @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

  startwebview();

  webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
  webView.loadUrl(current_page_url);
  initWebView();


   private void initWebView() {
    webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
        @Override
        public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
            super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
            current_page_url = url;
            invalidateOptionsMenu();
        }

        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            webView.loadUrl(url);
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, WebResourceRequest request) {
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
                webView.loadUrl(request.getUrl().toString());
            }
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            super.onPageFinished(view, url);
            invalidateOptionsMenu();
        }

        @Override
        public void onReceivedError(WebView view, WebResourceRequest request, WebResourceError error) {
            super.onReceivedError(view, request, error);
            invalidateOptionsMenu();
        }
    });

    WebSettings webSettings = webView.getSettings();
    webSettings.setLayoutAlgorithm(WebSettings.LayoutAlgorithm.NARROW_COLUMNS);
    webView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
    webView.getSettings().setSupportZoom(true);
    webView.getSettings().setDisplayZoomControls(false);
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());

}

  public void startwebview(){
    webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
    webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/web/index.html");
}
```

**My jquery html files get information from these js and css:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Home</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css">
<script src="jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>


</head> 
<body> 
<ul data-role="listview">

<li><a href="index/index.html" rel="external"><font style="white-space:normal; font-size: normal"></font></a></li>

</ul>
</body>
</html>
```